# Get a column value to be replaced with another column value based on condition

Tags: pandas

Getting errors when replacing a column value with another column's value based on condition.

Here is the code...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
'D' : [1, 2, 1, 3],
'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
'F' : 'foo' })
```

Want to replace value of column E with F, if value of column D == 1.

Tried the following alternatives...

**Alternative A:**

```
df[df.D == 1]['E'] = df[df.D == 1]['F']
```

This gives `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

**Alternative B:**

```
mask = df['D'] == 1
df.loc[mask, 'E'] = df.loc[mask, 'F']
```

...gives `ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first`

**Alternative C:**

```
df.loc[mask, 'E'].replace(df.loc[mask, 'F'])
df
```

...simply doesn't do anything.

Where am I going wrong? What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the Categorical's categories allows this to work:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : 1.,
   ...: 'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
   ...: 'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
   ...: 'D' : [1, 2, 1, 3],
   ...: 'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"], categories=['test', 'train', 'foo']),
   ...: 'F' : 'foo' })

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
     A          B    C  D      E    F
0  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  1   test  foo
1  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  2  train  foo
2  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  1   test  foo
3  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  3  train  foo

In [9]: df.loc[df.D == 1, 'E'] = df.F

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
     A          B    C  D      E    F
0  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  1    foo  foo
1  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  2  train  foo
2  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  1    foo  foo
3  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  3  train  foo
```